# How do I ignore/delete points in the ocean when extracting values from a map using raster::extract?

Tags: r, extract, raster

I have a list of coordinates from recorded sightings for a plant species.

I am extracting mean annual temperature from a map at each coordinate (using `raster::extract`).

But I now realise that a few coordinates are in the ocean due to some sampling error (e.g. they are just off the coast), causing the extracted values from maps to be inaccurate, because the map only gives information about terrestrial sites.

Is there a quick way of removing ocean coordinates form the list of coordinates, or ignoring ocean coordinates when extracting temperature values from the map? (I have to do this for many species and environmental variables)

Thank you

Comment: Help others reproduce your problem.  Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: also have a look at [how to ask a great R question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/3250126)

Comment: Without knowing your exact data and site, I would use additional data sets, which allow for exclusion of such incorrect coordinates. One that comes to mind would be the GADM data. If you work only in one (or few) countr(y/ies), this is very easily done by using `getData('FRA', 'GADM')` (here: France) and subsetting your points with the administrative boundaries. However, keep in mind that is not that accurate. Another possibility would be to use OSM coastline polygon data.

Comment: Further, think about moving this question over to https://gis.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use `na.omit` or similar *after* you extract the values and detect the `NA`s

Example data:

```
library(raster)
set.seed(1)
r <- raster(ncol=36, nrow=18, vals=1:(18*36))
r[sample(ncell(r), 300)] = NA
s <- stack(r, r)
names(s) <- c('temperature', 'rain')
xy <- cbind(lon=-50, lat=seq(-80, 80, by=20))
sp <- data.frame(sp=rep(c('A', 'B', 'C'), 3), xy)
```

Use extract

```
e <- extract(s, xy)
x <- data.frame(sp, e)
x
#  sp lon lat temperature rain
#1  A -50 -80          NA   NA
#2  B -50 -60          NA   NA
#3  C -50 -40         482  482
#4  A -50 -20          NA   NA
#5  B -50   0         338  338
#6  C -50  20         266  266
#7  A -50  40          NA   NA
#8  B -50  60         122  122
#9  C -50  80          NA   NA

y <- na.omit(x)
y
#  sp lon lat temperature rain
#3  C -50 -40         482  482
#5  B -50   0         338  338
#6  C -50  20         266  266
#8  B -50  60         122  122
```